# Adding cocos2d to an existing xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add cocos2d to an existing project.

I found this: [Adding Cocos2D only to already existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458744/adding-cocos2d-only-to-already-existing-project)

which looks like exactly what I want.. however, I downloaded cocos2d from the website and I don't have a `FontLabel` folder or file..? whatever it's supposed to be.

I followed the rest of the instructions and I keep getting errors where it says cannot find: `kazmath/SOME_FILE.h` so I imported the `kazmath` directory into the project as well, but the same error kept persisting.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a better/easier way to link cocos2d with an existing project?
2. Why does it keep looking for the `kazmath` files even though they're there? (I cleaned and rebuilt the project many times).
3. Where can I get this `FontLabel` and is it important that I have it?

Comment: Did you link the linker flags? Step 5. That generally create the error. Font label folder is the file that works with placing labels on the screen such as score etc.

Comment: @CodeMonkey yes, I did the linker flags. Although I'm not sure what -lz flag is? I just copied it.

Comment: add kazmath to search path. The question refers to cocos2d 1.x hence the discrepancies

Comment: Is that done by added `"$(SRCROOT)/kazmath"` to the Library Search Paths under Build Settings? If so.. it's not working still.

Comment: HEADER search path, not library

Comment: I add `"$(SRCROOT)/kazmath"` to the Header Search Path and took it out of the Library Search Path and it still doesn't work. I get a `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'kazmath/mat4.h' file not found` although those files are there.

Comment: hi,@cskoala I am getting the same issue. do you have solution for that?