# How to integrate cocos2d-iphone-3.1.0 into existing iOS project?

Tags: ios7, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6

I am working on old project in which i need to update code. The project also uses cocos 2d older version. When i build project with latest Xcode 6.0, it gives many errors. I tried the old way to integrate. I followed the steps given into [Adding Cocos2D only to already existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458744/adding-cocos2d-only-to-already-existing-project) not solves my problem. I am getting error like "Could not build module 'UIKit' " and many more similar error for other framework. So i decided to integrate new version of cocos 2d 3.1.0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also searching for the same solution, if you find any solution then please let me know. Thanks